# Merging multiple files with null values using AWK

Tags: awk, sed

Sorry I am posting it again as i messed up in my earlier post:
I am interesting in joining multiple files (e.g., file 1 file2 file 3...) using matching values in column 1 and get this desired output. Would appreciate any help please:

file1:

```
A 2 3 4
B 3 7 8
C 4 6 9
```

file2:

```
A 7 6 3
C 2 4 7 
D 1 6 4
```

file3:

```
A 3 2 7 
B 4 7 3 
E 3 6 8
```

Output:

```
A 2 3 4 7 6 3 3 2 7
B 3 7 8 n n n 4 7 3
C 4 6 9 2 4 7 n n n
D n n n 1 6 4 n n n
E n n n n n n 3 6 8
```

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable, **textual** (not images and not links) sample input and expected output plus what you've tried so far and where you're struggling. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Comment: I was just about to make the same comment, but I'll add that the way you have it laid out in the image is perfect, it just needs to be included in the question as text so people can copy and paste it easily to test their solutions.

Comment: Can you please provide code showing what you have tried?

Comment: so far i tried this, and it worked partially:   awk 'NR==FNR {h[$1] = $0; next} {print $1,$2,$3,$4,h[$1]}' file2.txt file1.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one for awk. Tested with GNU awk, mawk, original-awk ie. awk 20121220 and Busybox awk:

```
$ awk '
function nn(c,   b,i) {
    if(c)
        for(i=1;i<=c;i++)
            b=b "n "
    return b
}
FNR==1{nf+=(NF-1)}
{
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)
        b[$1]=b[$1] $i OFS
    a[$1]=a[$1] (n[$1]<(nf-NF+1)?nn(nf-NF+1-n[$1]):"") b[$1]
    n[$1]=nf+0
    delete b[$1]
}
END{
    for(i in a)
        print i,a[i] (n[i]<(nf)?nn(nf-n[i]):"") 
}' file1 file2 file3
```

Output:

```
A 2 3 4 7 6 3 3 2 7 
B 3 7 8 n n n 4 7 3 
C 4 6 9 2 4 7 n n n 
D n n n 1 6 4 n n n 
E n n n n n n 3 6 8
```

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Copy & paste your code and use the code sample `{}` function of the editor.

Comment: @Freddy I sure won't but if you check the question's edit history you'll get my point. Also, in the future I may (probably won't) start pointing image-only questioners here.

Comment: Hahaha - post a picture of your data, get a picture of a solution in return - I understand why this is not a good idea, but it does seem fair...

Answer (score 0):

A different approach (same outcome) using GNU awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
        FS = OFS = " "
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_str_asc"
}

FNR == 1 {
        filecount++
        numfields[filecount] = NF
        if (NR == 1) {
                a = split($0, header, FS)
        } else {
                for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {
                        header[++a] = $i
                }
        }
}

FNR > 1 {
        for (j = 2; j <= NF; j++) {
                b[$1][filecount, j] = $j
        }
}

END {
        for (k = 1; k <= length(header); k++) {
                printf "%s%s", header[k], ((k < length(header)) ? OFS : ORS)
        }
        for (l in b) {
                printf "%s", l OFS
                for (m = 1; m <= filecount; m++) {
                        for (n = 2; n <= numfields[m]; n++) {
                                printf "%s%s",
                                (b[l][m, n] == "" ? "n" : b[l][m, n]),
                                ((m + n < filecount + numfields[m]) ? OFS : ORS)
                        }
                }
        }
}' File*.csv
A 2 3 4 7 6 3 3 2 7
B 3 7 8 n n n 4 7 3
C 4 6 9 2 4 7 n n n
D n n n 1 6 4 n n n
E n n n n n n 3 6 8
```

This solution can handle a discordant number of fields between files, it fills missing values, and processes the header separately so the rest of the output can be sorted.

With different example data:

```
head file*
==> file1 <==
ID,Value
A1,10
A2,20
A3,30
A4,40

==> file2 <==
ID,Score,Extra
A2,200,True
A1,100,False

==> file3 <==
ID,Evaluation
A1,Correct
A3,Incorrect

==> file4 <==
ID,Value1,Value2,Value3,Value4
A1,,1,1
A2,3,3,3,3

awk 'BEGIN {
        FS = OFS = ","
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_str_asc"
}

FNR == 1 {
        filecount++
        numfields[filecount] = NF
        if (NR == 1) {
                a = split($0, header, FS)
        } else {
                for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {
                        header[++a] = $i
                }
        }
}

FNR > 1 {
        for (j = 2; j <= NF; j++) {
                b[$1][filecount, j] = $j
        }
}

END {
        for (k = 1; k <= length(header); k++) {
                printf "%s%s", header[k], ((k < length(header)) ? OFS : ORS)
        }
        for (l in b) {
                printf "%s", l OFS
                for (m = 1; m <= filecount; m++) {
                        for (n = 2; n <= numfields[m]; n++) {
                                printf "%s%s",
                                (b[l][m, n] == "" ? "NA" : b[l][m, n]),
                                ((m + n < filecount + numfields[m]) ? OFS : ORS)
                        }
                }
        }
}' file*
ID,Value,Score,Extra,Evaluation,Value1,Value2,Value3,Value4
A1,10,100,False,Correct,NA,1,1,NA
A2,20,200,True,NA,3,3,3,3
A3,30,NA,NA,Incorrect,NA,NA,NA,NA
A4,40,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data is sorted you can use coreutils `join` like this:

```
join -a1 -a2 -o auto -e n <(join -a1 -a2 -o auto -e n file1 file2) file3
```

Or for an arbitrary number of files:

```
rm out; touch out
for f in file*; do
  join -o auto -a1 -a2 -e n out $f > tmp
  mv tmp out
done
cat out
```